# VBA: Dim Control Object Failed

Tags: vba

Just have no clue why the code below kept complaining about "user defined type not defined":

```
Dim ownControl As Control
```

I saw all other resources online used this code without any problem. Really confuse on it, hope someone can explain to me.

By the way, I'm using MS Excel 2007. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you will need to first add a UserForm to your workbook (assuming you're going to be using one) or instead add a reference to "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library".

The `Control` type is defined in that library.

Comment: Thanks a lot, TW. I solved the problem by creating a UseForm first so that the "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" would be added. Appreciate your clue.